# Swift - Changing background color to transparent

Tags: swift

I noticed one of my buttons has a value for the background color = 'default'

When the button is highlighted I want to change a different button to also have a 'default' background color, here is my code so far:

```
@IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {

    registerBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.highlighted);
}
```

How do I achieve this so registerBtn has a background color which is basically transparent?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What's color is named 'default'? Single quotes? That shouldn't work syntactically. Also, if the code you've posted is for the button where you ant the action to take place, you are obviously using IB, so why not (a) code for buttonHighlighted instead and then (b) set an IBOutlet on the second button and set the background color for .touchUpInside? You know, after writing this I'm beginning to think your logic is simply backwards.

Comment: Sorry I meant within the inspector panel of XCode the background color of the button is set to default. And Im just a beginner with Swift so you could please emphasise what you mean with some code? All im really trying to achieve is change the background color of the button when the button is highlighted @dfd

Comment: I'll post an answer. Maybe that's the best way to do this. If you have questions, put them in the comments on my answer. I'll try to edit things as we get things straightened out.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why do you not use backgroundColor property? Like this: registerBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear , or you can modify in the storyboard, the State Config property to Highlighted and set the backgroundColor

Comment: @Carol, I agree - in part. It sounds like the desire is to change the backgroundColor of another button when the first button is highlighted. If so, that requires some code.

Comment: @KTOV, a few things on my current answer: (1) If you want to change the background color of "secondButton", why is your question coded to change titleColor? (2) Can you explain a bit more high-level what you are trying to do? It's not a normally seen thing to change the backgroundColor of a second button when the first is highlighted - maybe when tapped?

Comment: Basically, my button (registerBtn) currently has an orange background and white text color.. when it is highlighted I want to change the background color from orange to transparent and the text color from white to orange.. Do you understand now? @dfd

Comment: Yes, and I've updated everything in my answer that should make it work perfectly for you. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the comments I found that:

- Both buttons are created in InterfaceBuilder (IB).
- The background color of each button is either set to *default* or something else in IB.
- The idea is to have the second button have a transparent background color and a white title when the first is highlighted.

(I'll edit the above as needed. Among the things I'm not entirely sure about is what should happen after when the first button is no longer highlighted.)

If the above is the situation, you need to do the following:

- Have the first button do things when **either** UIControlEventTouchDown or UIControlEventTouchDragEnter happen.
- Have the first button then change the background color of the second through code.

Probably the easiest way to do this is **not** through IB, but instead through code. After adding your buttons in IB, create IBOutlets for both of them. Then you can do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(highlightSecondButton), for: .touchDown)
    firstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(highlightSecondButton), for: .touchDragEnter)
}

func highlightSecondButton(_ sender:UIButton) {
    secondButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    secondButton.backgroundColor = nil
}
```

Comment: You see one of my buttons has a transparent background (no background color at all) how do you change this in code, so the buttons background color could be set to transparent? if you get what i mean

Comment: Hah! just learned something new today - something good to know. Swift 3 changed things from UIColor.transparentColor to simply nil. I updated and test the code in my answer.

Comment: Your code works perfect! Was wondering, if perhaps i wanted to reset the button background color back to white would I have to have a new event which would detect for touchUp or something?

Comment: The sequential(?) event to .touchDragEnter is .touchDragExit, but I'm not sure what it is for .touchDown - I think you need both .touchUpInside and .touchUpOutside.

Answer (score 6):

Use `UIColor.clear` to make a color transparent.

It is very confusing that Apple calls it "default" instead of "clear."

Answer (score 0):

> Swift

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

> objective-C

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```